# How to call a function in main v8 loop from a different thread

Tags: c++, node.js, native, libuv

I am trying to implement an audio module for nodejs which involves a neural network.

This neural network has 2 types of nodes

1. Pure C++
2. C++ based on JAVASCRIPT ( which involves calling a javascript
   function  )

As far as i know its not possible to call any function which involves v8 from a different thread. And if i return to the main thread i will lose my traverse in the neural network.

How to implement a call to a function in the main thread from a different thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of

@indutny in the #libuv channel.

What I do now is dispatch the call to main thread via

```
uv_async_send
```

function defined in `libuv.h`, since the function is non-blocking. I also use a semaphore to wait till the execution of the javascript function is complete in order to avoid the corrupted parse.